# Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Maximum of a Sample from a Uniform Distribution:

Suppose $X_1, ...  , X_n$ is a random sample for a $\mathrm{uniform}(0,\theta)$ distribution. Suppose $\theta$ is unknown. An intuitive estimate of $\theta$ is the maximum of a sample. Let $Y_n = \max\{X_1, ... , X_n\}$. Exercise 5.1.4 shows that the cdf of $Y_n$ is

$F_{Y_n}(t) = 1$ if $t>\theta$, $F_{Y_n}(t) = \frac{t^n}{\theta^n}$ if $0 < t \leq \theta$, and $F_{Y_n}(t) = 0$ if $t\le0$.

Then the pdf of $Y_n$ is $f_{Y_n}(t) = \frac{nt^{n-1}}{\theta^n}$ if $0 < t \leq \theta$, and $f_{Y_n}(t) = 0$ elsewhere.

Based on its pdf, it is easy to show that $E(Y_n) = (n/(n+1))\theta$. Thus, $Y_n$ is a biased estimator $\theta$... Further, based on the cdf of $Y_n$, it is easily seen that $Y_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability.

MY QUESTION:

> How do we know that $Y_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability? Is it because $E(Y_n) \rightarrow \theta$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484567/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of *convergence in probability* is given below :

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space. then we say that $\{X_n\}$ **convergence in probability** to $\theta$ if for every $\epsilon >0$,
>   $$Pr[|X_n-\theta| \geq \epsilon]\rightarrow0  ~\text{as}~ n\rightarrow \infty$$ and this is equivalent to $$Pr[|X_n-\theta|< \epsilon]\rightarrow 1  ~\text{as}~ n\rightarrow \infty$$

For your problem note that $$\begin{align}P[|Y_{(n)}-\theta|< \epsilon] &=P[\theta-\epsilon<Y_{(n)}<\theta+\epsilon]\\ &= F_{Y_{(n)}}(\theta+\epsilon)- F_{Y_{(n)}}(\theta-\epsilon)\\&= 1-(\frac{\theta-\epsilon}{\theta})^n, 0< \epsilon <\theta \\&=1-0,\epsilon  \geq\theta \\& \rightarrow 1 ~\text{as}~ n \to \infty\end{align}$$
Hence $Y_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability.

Comment: How did you passed from line 2 to line 3 in your answer above?  I mean, how did you get $F_Y(\theta+\epsilon) - F_Y(\theta-\epsilon) = 1-(\frac{\theta-\epsilon}{\theta})^n$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $E \left[ Y_n \right] \rightarrow \theta$ so that $E \left[ \left|
Y_n - \theta \right| \right] \rightarrow 0$, you could use [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)
to show that for $\varepsilon > 0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ \left| Y_n - \theta \right| \geq \varepsilon \right] & \leqslant & E
  \left[ \left| Y_n - \theta \right| \right]/\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
which goes to zero proving convergence in probability.

Comment: Thanks, but then we need to have epsilon next to $Pr[|Y_n - \theta| \geq \epsilon]$, right? Like this...\begin{eqnarray*}
  \epsilon \Pr \left[ \left| Y_n - \theta \right| \geq \varepsilon \right] & \leqslant & E
  \left[ \left| Y_n - \theta \right| \right]
\end{eqnarray*} Do we ignore that epsilon, because it is arbitrarily small?

Comment: I think $Pr[|Y_n-\theta| \geq \epsilon] \leq \frac {E[|Y_n-\theta|]}{\epsilon}$ not $E[|Y_n-\theta|]$, from Markov.

Comment: @Artus and A.D. Sorry about my typo. I added the missing epsilon.