# Convergence of probability of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I was looking at this post because there was something similar in my school's lecture slide [Convergence in Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288018/convergence-in-probability).

However in my school's slide it didn't mention how it got the cdf so I have 2 questions.

What does it mean to take the maximum of a set of distributions? My understanding is that the distribution $X_n$ is just a set of data that generates a pattern that can be modeled/estimated by a distribution, so what does $\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ mean?

How do you get $F_{Y_n}(t) = \frac{t^n}{\theta^n}$, since it's a uniform distribution the density function would be $f_y(t) = \frac{1}{\theta}$ but integrating $f_y(t)$ between $0$ to $t$ does not give me $F_{Y_n}(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. To get some intuition as to what $\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ means lets look at what we are assigning this quantity to:
$$Y_n=\max\{X_1,...,X_N\}$$
$Y_n$ is a **random variable**, so all we are doing is looking at a function of a set of random variables. We aren't picking one out and saying this one is the max, we can only do that once we have a realization of the data. Instead, we are just writing down a symbol for the concept of the max of a random sample so that we can do algebra on it.

For your second question: you are basically already there.

What is $P(Y_n <y)$? Well if the *max* is less than $y$ then *all* $X_i$ are less than $y$. **If** those $X_i$ are i.i.d then the product of the joint distribution 
$$P(X_1 <y,X_2<y,...,X_n<y)$$

factors into the product of the marginals
$$\prod_{i=1}^nP(X_i<y)$$
and you already know the formula for the marginal density function, so find the marginal cdf and plug-in!

Answer (score 1):

The $X_i$ don't denote "distributions" but random variables.

Let's do an example. Throw a fair die (independently) $n$ times. Let $X_i$ be the value of the $i$-th throw. An experiment might give (for $n=5$) $X_1=3$, $X_2=5$, $X_3=3$, $X_4=5$ and $X_5=2$. In this case $\max(X_1,\ldots,X_5)=5$ for this outcome. So $\max(X_1,\ldots,X_5)$ is a random variable. It takes values in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ like the $X_i$ do,
but it is more likely to take larger values than smaller ones.

Comment: thank you very much! your explanation helped alot but I can only choose one accepted answer