# Convergence of maximum of uniform R.V. to distribution parameter

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution

Can someone please help me to prove the convergence (in probability) of the maximum of uniform R.V. to distribution parameter:

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$ be i.i.d. uniform R.V. in $[0, \theta]$, for some $\theta >0$. Further, let $M_{n} = \max_{i=1,2,...,n} X_{i}$. I want to prove this: $\lim_{n \to \infty} M_{n} \to \theta$.

Intuitively, it makes sense that this would occur: as we sample more and more points from the distribution, it becomes more and more likely to sample points closer to the right end of the distribution domain. More mathematical intuition is as follows,

$P(M_{n} \geq \theta ) = 0$, and

$\forall t \in [0,\theta], P(M_{n} \leq \theta -t) = \left(1-\frac{t}{\theta} \right)^n$.

The first equation tells us that the maximum is always less than $\theta$, which is obviously true, and the second equation talks about the distance of maximum from $\theta$, i.e. for really high values of $n$ and small values for $\frac{t}{\theta}$, the probability is squeezed towards the actual parameter value of $\theta$.

I guess we can use Law of Large numbers to prove this, but I am not sure how to apply it here.

Edit: I just realized, in other words, I am looking to prove that $M_{n}$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$.

Comment: If you want to show $M_n$ is consistent, it follows from definition: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484567/321264. Also type of convergence is not clear from saying '$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_{n} \to \theta$'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the sequence $M_n=Max(X_1,...,X_n)$ is bounded in $[0;\theta]$ and it is monotone. In fact

$M_{n+1}=Max[M_n, X_{n+1}]\geq M_n$

So applying a known theorem $M_n \rightarrow \theta$

- almost surely
- in probability
- in Distribution

Comment: I think you are referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem. So, just to be sure, LLN is not even applicable here, right? Don't know why LLN popped up in my head and I was trying hard to apply here. This is pretty interesting. There are other limit theorems that are applicable in statistics.

Comment: Yes. Of course it is not forbidden to prove in other ways the weak convergence...it is always a good exercise!

Comment: To prove the weak convergence (in probability) and applying the definition you have only to calculate $\mathbb{P}[|M_n-\theta|>\epsilon]=F_M(\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon^n}{\theta^n}\rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. As the sequence converges in probability, it converges also il Law

Comment: This is great, thanks!