# Convergence in probability with a maximum value

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution

Let X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>,...,X<sub>n</sub> be i.i.d. continuous random variables of the uniform distribution $Unif(0, \beta$), $\beta>0$.
Consider M<sub>n</sub> = max<sub>1≤i≤n</sub> X<sub>i</sub>. Prove that M<sub>n</sub> converges in probability to $\beta$.

I know how to prove a sample $\bar X$ converges in probability to an expected value $\mu$ with the Chebyshev's inequality $P(|\bar X-\mu|> {\epsilon})\le \frac{{\sigma}^2}{{\epsilon}^2}$ with (in this case) E(X<sub>i</sub>) = ${\mu}=\frac{\beta}{2}$ and Var(X<sub>i</sub>) = $\frac{\beta^2}{12}$, but the new concept of M<sub>n</sub> = max<sub>1≤i≤n</sub> X<sub>i</sub> added to this confuses me a lot.

Can someone explain this to me? Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [Convergence in Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288018/convergence-in-probability). Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484567/321264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $M_n \overset{p}{\to} \beta$, a constant, if and only if $M_n \overset{d}{\to}\beta$ (convergence in distribution).

Let us then consider the CDF of $M_n$ for each $n$.

As an exercise, prove that the CDF of $M_n$ is given by
$$F_{M_n}(m) = \begin{cases}
0, & m \leq 0\\
\left(\dfrac{m}{\beta}\right)^n, & 0 < m < \beta \\
1, & m \geq\beta
\end{cases}$$
Then it is clear that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{M_n}(m) = \begin{cases}
0, & m  < \beta \\
1, & m \geq \beta
\end{cases}$$
which is identical in distribution to a random variable which is equal to $\beta$ with probaiblity $1$. Thus, $M_n \overset{d}{\to}\beta$, implying $M_n \overset{p}{\to} \beta$.